# Find a basis for Each corresponding eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$= $\begin{bmatrix} 
-5 & 1 & 5 \\
-7 & 4 & 4 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

I now want to find the eigenctvectors of $A$ and the basis corresponding to each eigenspaces.

**Attempt at finding the solution**

$1.$ Find the eigenvalues:

The roots of the charecteristic polynomial of $A$ are $-4, 3, 1$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-4, 3$ and $ 1$

$2.$ Find the eigenvectors:

1. Eigen vector $V1$

We get the system:

$31x+4y=0$

$-7x+4z=0$

So we have $V1 =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
-4/31 \\
4/7
\end{bmatrix}$

2. Eigenvector $V2$

similarly we get:  $V2 =  \begin{bmatrix} 
-1/3 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

3. Eigenvector $V3$

And $V3 =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

**Now my problem is I don't know how to find the eigenspaces corresponding and therefore cannot find its basis**

Comment: A eigenspace is $E_{\lambda} = \{v \in E ; Av = \lambda v\}$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

For example, the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is
$$E_{\lambda1}=\{tv_1=(t, -\frac{4t}{31}, \frac{4t}{7})^T, t∈F \}$$

Then any element $v$ of $E_{\lambda1}$ will satisfy $Av=\lambda_1 v$.
The basis of $E_{\lambda1}$ can be $\{(1, -\frac{4}{31}, \frac{4}{7})^T\}$, and now you can find other two eigenspaces and bases.

Comment: Are the eigenvectors I found the respective basis of the eigenspaces?

Comment: It can be. But you can may choose other one using a constant $a$(not zero) like $av_1$.

Comment: Also in other cases, two (or more) independent eigenvectors can be found  corresponding to one eigenvalue $\lambda$. In that case the basis of $E_\lambda$ can consist of two (or more) eigenvectors you found.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've found the eigenvalues $\lambda=-4,3,1$, row reduce $(-4 I-A),(3I-A),$ and $(I-A)$. Once you've done that, solve $(\lambda I-A)v=0$ for each $\lambda$ (i.e. determine $\text{null}(\lambda I - A)$ for every $\lambda$). The $\text{null}(\lambda I - A)$ are your eigenspaces! The basis of each eigenspace is the span of the linearly independent vectors you get from row reducing and solving $(\lambda I - A)v = 0$.